# OneToOneField QuerySet returning empty dict

Tags: django

I have 2 models called Manufacturer and Car . The Car model has a foreignKey to Manufacturer which mean a many cars can belong to a single Manufacturer.
 In the model manfacturer , their is an OneToOneField called showcase which allows a Manufacturer to have a single car to showcase,
How can I show all the Manufacturers which have a car to showcase which mean , show all Manufacturer with a OneToOneField objects.

I tried Manufacturer.objects.filter(showcase=True) but it return an empty dictionary []

```
class Manufacturer(models.Model):


    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    showcase = models.OneToOneField('Car',related_name='Car',blank=True)



class Car(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    Manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer,blank=False,related_name='Manufacturer')
```

Comment: How is this an error? maybe try something like .filter(showcase__pk__gt=0)?

Comment: @fsw , What does the 0 mean?

Comment: it means to select manufacturers with showcase with primary key greater than 0. I haven't tested it just an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Manufacturer.objects.exclude(showcase=None)`

also, in your model try to add `null=True` next to to `blank=True` in the showcase attribute of the model.

Comment: I don't know, it's really strange because when I tested it, it worked

Comment: did you test your one or mine one?

Comment: I tried both, and they both worked fine for me (only I added the null=True, otherwise it didn't allow me to add a manufacturer without a showcase). I used Django 1.5.1.